# Laravel mix static with dynamic slug in a base route

Tags: laravel

I have a question and I don't find a solution, I'm building a landing page section and in this section I will have some pages with identical layout, and content will be provider by db, some other pages will return a blade view.

How can I manager the route?

Url structure will be domani.com/landing/{slug}

Which is the best way to compare the {slug} with provider static slug and if not find search in the db?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your route a where condition. Like that?

```
Route::get('/landing/{page}', App\Http\Controllers\LandingPageController::class)
    ->name('page')
    ->where('page', 'about-us|imprint|contact');
```

In this example only `/landingpage/about-us`, `/landingpage/imprint`, `/landingpage/contact` requestable.

And in your LandingPageController you can add a method with a switch case to redirect to the right page.

```
class LandingPageController {

    public function __invoke($page)
    {
        return view('pages.'.$page);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmh... I'm not understanding your example, how can I return a view for each static route name?

Comment: @StefanoMartini I updated my answear. I add the LandingPageController with an invoke funtion. Then you will understand it better what i mean.